# После скрытия меню паузы персонаж атакует один раз

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня в аниматоре 3 состояния, которые соответствуют 3м анимациям атаки, срабатывают по триггеру из Any State(Attack1, Attack2, Attack3). Вот скрипт, который отвечает за смену анимаций.

```
private void CheckInputCombat()
    {
        m_timeSinceAttack += Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && m_timeSinceAttack > 0.25f && !HeroTakeHurt.isDead)
        {
            m_currentAttack++;
            if (m_currentAttack > 3)
                m_currentAttack = 1;
            if (m_timeSinceAttack > 1.0f)
                m_currentAttack = 1;
            animator.SetTrigger("Attack" + m_currentAttack);
            m_timeSinceAttack = 0.0f;
        }
    }
```

В то же время есть в другом скрипте метод, который вызывается при нажатии кнопки "Возобновить игру" из меню паузы:

```
public void Resume()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        gameIsPaused = false;
    }
```

вызывается по условию в Update():

```
void Update(){
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (gameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            }
            else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        } 
}
```

И проблема то в том, что нажатие кнопки "Возобновить" приводит к тому, что выполняется анимация по срабатыванию триггера и персонаж лишний раз атакует.
На всякий покажу ещё аниматор: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ты нажимаешь лкм -> `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && m_timeSinceAttack > 0.25f && !HeroTakeHurt.isDead)` это условие == true -> проигрывается анимация и абсолютно не важно на паузе игра или нет.

Comment: @KOTlK, сделайте как ответ это помогло мне, спасибо.